# CSS3 translateX confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The problem is, that `translateX` is not changing it's position right before animating. In the example problematic slide is `#slide2`, i'm changing it's position before animating and it still animate from the wrong side.

How to fix that behavior? Using css `left` property instead is fixing this, but i want to use `translateX`.

Thanks.

html:

```
<div id="slide1"></div>
<div id="slide2"></div>
```

css:

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
#slide2 {
    background:blue;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

javascript:

```
$('#slide2')
    .css('-webkit-transition','none')
    .css('-webkit-transform','translateX(-100%)');

$('#slide1').css('-webkit-transform','translateX(100%)');

$('#slide2')
    .css('-webkit-transition','all 0.4s linear')
    .css('-webkit-transform','translateX(0%)');
```

jsfiddle playground:
http://jsfiddle.net/D5d9e/

Comment: If you're not getting the answers you want, it might be because people don't understand your question.

Comment: Isn't code is clear enough? And my answer too? Ask what is not understandable, because I don't know.

Comment: If the code isn't doing what you want it to do, you will need to explain what you want it to do. If your code does X, but you want Y, you need to *clearly* explain Y.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** - Try this:

```
$('#slide2')
    .css('-webkit-transition','none')
    .css('-webkit-transform','translateX(-100%)')
    .css('-webkit-transform'); // wtf happens here
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D5d9e/6/

This works... for some reason.

Comment: no no , you don't get it, initial position SHOULD be 100%, because previously it were animated from left to right.

Comment: Why it's not changing it to -100% as i'm telling it to do, before animating?

Comment: I have found a fix as well, it's strange. Not sure why it's happening this way. It seems that transform calls are asynchronous and first call gets overwritten by second right away and is ignored? http://jsfiddle.net/D5d9e/8/

Comment: Ahaha your answer is even more creepy. :D I'm even more confused. Any guru here, who can explain that? :D

Comment: That makes sense now actually. All those `.css()` calls are happening in one go, so the translation to 0% will immediately override the translation to -100%. They're all synchronous, actually. But that still doesn't explain why my example works!